# How to prompt for autofll in another app?

Tags: android, android-studio, autofill, android-autofill-manager

I am making a password manager, in which i am storing passwords of different user.

How do i prompt him to fill data/credentials from our database.

like how different password protector is doing it.
I am also storing their data locally.

[image: This is what i am trying to achieve.]

Comment: Check out the documentation for the [Autofill framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill)

Comment: I am not able to do it, reading docs.
Is there any tutorials on this? @AlexanderHoffmann

Comment: You can check out the [Autofill codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/optimize-autofill/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) or download the full sample code on the [input-samples Repository](https://github.com/android/input-samples/tree/master/AutofillFramework).

Answer (score 3):

For Android API 26(Android 8.0) or greater, you can use [Auto-fill Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofillFor), which has all the inbuilt support needed for Auto-fill along with UI.

For older Android versions, you have to use [Accessibility Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service) to detect (as well as paste data) when user is entering something and manually show suggestions by drawing on the top of others apps.

Comment: I am not able to do it, reading docs.
Is there any tutorials on this?

Comment: @Test The official documentation is good enough. Here are other tutorials - https://medium.com/better-programming/exploring-the-autofill-framework-in-android-672221ccdc6a https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-android-os-autofill-framework--cms-28811

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, Will check that!!